# Scrolling in multiple directions with nested RecyclerViews + AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I've been having trouble with `AppBarLayout` behavior. I have a basic setup of an `AppBarLayout` to hide the Toolbar whenever I scroll and that works as expected, however, because my vertical scrolling view is composed of multiple horizontal scrolling views whenever I start the vertical scroll by touching on any of the horizontal scrolling views the `AppBarLayout` won't catch the scroll. I've been debugging and the `layoutDependsOn` or the `onNested[Pre]Scroll` are not triggered in the `AppBarLayout`'s behavior.

However, if I start the **scroll** on any area which isn't a horizontal recycler it triggers the AppBarLayout's behavior. **Flinging** works regardless of the starting point of the touch.

How can I fix that?

My structure is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation here on SO I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34318170/7913860 which solved my issue.

The key is to have `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` on the inner recyclers